# How to use scl command as a script shebang?

Tags: python-2.7, rhel, shebang, software-collections

If I want to run a specific command (with arguments) under Software Collections, I can use this command:

```
scl enable python27 "ls /tmp"
```

However, if I try to make a shell script that has a similar command as its shebang line, I get errors:

```
$ cat myscript
#!/usr/bin/scl enable python27 "ls /tmp"
echo hello

$ ./myscript
Unable to open /etc/scl/prefixes/"ls!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsing of arguments in the she-bang command is not really defined. From [`man execve`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve):

> The semantics of the optional-arg argument of an interpreter script vary across implementations. On Linux, the entire string following the interpreter name is passed as a single argument to the interpreter, and this string can include white space. However, behavior differs on some other systems. Some systems use the first white space to terminate optional-arg. On some systems, an interpreter script can have multiple arguments, and white spaces in optional-arg are used to delimit the arguments.

No matter what, argument splitting based on quote sis not supported. So when you write:

```
#!/usr/bin/scl enable python27 "ls /tmp"
```

It's very possible that what gets invoked is (using bash notation):

```
'/usr/bin/scl' 'enable' 'python27' '"ls' '/tmp"'
```

This is probably why it tries to open the `"ls` file at `/etc/scl/prefixes/"ls`

But it is just as likely that the shebang evaluates to:

```
'/usr/bin/scl' 'enable python27 "ls /tmp"'
```

And that would fail since it wont be able to find a command named `enable python27 "ls /tmp"` for scl to execute.

There's a few workarounds you can use.

You can call your script via scl:

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash
echo hello

$ scl enable python27 ./myscript
hello
```

You can also use the [heredoc](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_documents) notation, but it might lead to subtle issues. I personally avoid this:

```
$ cat ./myscript
#!/bin/bash
scl enable python27 -- <<EOF
echo hi
echo \$X_SCLS
EOF

$ bash -x myscript 
+ scl enable python27 --
hi
python27
```

You can see one of the gotcha's already: I had to write `\$X_SCLS` to access the environment variable instead of just `$X_SCL`.

Edit: Another option is two have two scripts. One that has the actual code, and the second that simply does `scl enable python27 $FIRST_SCRIPT`. Then you wont have to remember to enter `scl ...` manually.

Answer (score 3):

You should try using `--` instead of surrounding your command with quotes.

`scl enable python27 -- ls /tmp`

I was able to make a python script that uses the rh-python35 collection with this shebang:

```py
#!/usr/bin/scl enable rh-python35 -- python

import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Answer (score 1):

The software collections [documentation](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/#sect-Running_Commands_Stored_in_a_File) may also be helpful. In particular you can try

```
cat myscript.sh | scl enable python27 -
```

As well as [permanently enabling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175851/how-to-permanently-enable-scl-centos-6-4) a software collection

```
source scl_source enable python27
./myscript.sh
```